# how to create a random string of alphabets and get text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am searching for methods to generate a string of alphabets and generate text to assert it, in selenium webDriver. 
i am trying to create a customer with random name. however, I have to search for the newly created customer and click on the text to enter further info.

Comment: Let me clarify. Do you want to generate a random string of characters to use for a customer name? What language?

Comment: Just going for alphabet is not a good idea. The first pitfall is when a customer has a name like "O'Mally" which has an apostrophe which wrecks havoc with database queries that are naively created by concatenation instead of prepared statements. You should generate names that have special characters, foreign letters, etc. - and using random will just make your tests unreliable and lengthy.

Comment: Yes Greg, you got that right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate random alphanumeric number as :-

```
import java.util.UUID;

String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

//Now this uuid enter to your text box
driver.findElement(By.id("text box id")).sendKeys(uuid);
```

Comment: How in the world does `72835145-4551-4199-91e3-67652a729750` somehow equate to a decent representation of a random person's name? With a UUID you are getting 0-9, -, and a-f... that's not even close to good.  I would suggest you look at RealSkeptic's comment and generate a list of names that represent good test cases and either use them all or randomly select from that list.

Comment: @JeffC what is the matter here if user wants only randomly generated string for testing purpose, why take extra effort, there is no need.

Comment: He asked for a "customer with random name." This nowhere near approximates a customer name.

Comment: @JeffC you just trying to make me incorrect?? He asked about random string which could be use as customer name, so string to be random doesn't matter how it is..:)

Comment: @JeffC you are absolutely right! the answer that Saurabh gave was not technically apt! however, it served my purpose.

Comment: @JeffC why not just give your own answer if you have a better one instead of finding faults?

Comment: @QAGuru Because SO is not just about answering questions, it's also about *feedback* for questions and answers. That's why they have the +1/-1 arrows. RealSkeptic had a good comment that pointed OP in the right direction and noscreenname had a good answer so there was no need to add another.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic(int)) from apache [commonlang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) api.

```
// random string of length 8 composed of alphabetic characters 
String s = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8); 

// random string of length 8 composed of alphabetic characters and numbers
String s = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8); 

// random string of length 8 composed only of lettes a, b, and c
String alphabet = "abc";
String s = RandomStringUtils.random(8, alphabet);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
public static String randomString(int intValue) throws Exception {
        char c[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int randomPosition;
        String randomString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < intValue; i++) {
            randomPosition = generateRandomIntIntRange(0, 51);
            randomString = randomString + c[randomPosition]; 
        }
        System.out.println(randomString);
        return randomString;        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting an answer try to elaborate a bit on your answer instead of just pasting some code. Also format your answer to be more readable.